# get files with two dots file name in the "recent files"

Tags: java, regex

I have an "Open recent file" button in my java application, and I can't seem to get to display the file with two dots in their file names (e.g., `sample.file.tpp`). One dot in the file name is working just fine though. I tried to play with regex parameter inside `String[] ext = f.getName().split()` but nothing is working. The code is as follows. Please help. Thanks.

```
public File showOpenDialog(Window ownerWindow){

    //ppt.load();

    fc.setInitialDirectory(ppt.getCurrent().toFile());

    File f = fc.showOpenDialog(ownerWindow);

    // Recent file settings
    if(f!=null){
        ppt.setCurrent(f.getParentFile().toString()) ;
        ppt.addLately(f);

        if(ppt.getLately()!=null){
            setMenuItems();

        }else{
        }


        String[] ext = f.getName().split("\\.");

        System.out.println(ext.length);

        if(ext.length > 1)
            if(ext[1].equals("tpp")){ 
                Main.setFileName(f.getName());
                saved = true;
            }

    }

    ppt.store();

    return f;
}



/**
 * Recent file settings
 * Returns null if it is not tpp file
 */
public File fileOpen(File f){
    ppt.load();

    fc.setInitialDirectory(ppt.getCurrent().toFile());

    // Recent file settings
    if(f!=null){
        ppt.setCurrent(f.getParentFile().toString()) ;
        ppt.addLately(f);

        if(ppt.getLately()!=null){
            setMenuItems();

        }else{
        }


        String[] ext = f.getName().split("\\.");

        System.out.println(ext.length);

        if(ext.length > 1)
            if(ext[1].equals("tpp")){ 
                Main.setFileName(f.getName());
                saved = true;
            }else return null;
        else return null;

    }
    ppt.store();
    return f;
}



public File showSaveDialog(Window ownerWindow){

    ppt.load();

    fc.setInitialDirectory(ppt.getCurrent().toFile());

    File f = fc.showSaveDialog(ownerWindow);


    // Recent file settings
    if(f!=null){
        ppt.setCurrent(f.getParentFile().toString()) ;
        ppt.addLately(f);

        if(ppt.getLately()!=null){
            setMenuItems();

        }else{
        }

        String[] ext = f.getName().split("\\.");

        System.out.println(ext.length);

        if(ext.length > 1)
            if(ext[1].equals("tpp")){
                Main.setFileName(f.getName());
                saved = true;
            }
    }

    ppt.store();

    return f;
}
```

Comment: If there are more than one dot, then `ext[1]` would not relate to the extension part.

Comment: `f.getName() != null && f.getName().endsWith(".tpp")`

Comment: What's your problem **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if(ext[1].equals("tpp"))...`

you should do `if(ext[length-1].equals("tpp"))..`

That's because if your filename is say `sample.file.tpp`, on splitting the the name you get an array with three elements: `sample`, `file` and `tpp`.

As you can see here, `tpp` will be the 3rd element in the array(ie. index = 2). So either you can do `ext[2]` or for scenarios with more than two dots, use `length-1` as the file extension will always be at the last.

Comment: If I change from `if(ext[1].equals("tpp"))` to `if(ext[length-1].equals("tpp"))`, I get a symbol not found error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try `if(ext[ext.length()-1].equals("tpp"))`

Comment: thanks for the answer, your solution above works for me or for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regexp for this case:

```
f.getName().endsWith(".tpp")
```